# are actors with Tokio the right approach for a data intensive application?

Tags: channel, actor, rust-tokio, mpsc

I'm working in a small rust crate whose purpose is to read data from server and write it to another, the data is received from a grpc endpoint and written to another grpc endpoint

the server and clients were created from proto definitions and they are created using tonic and Tokio runtime

the messages used by the grpc service will be contain around 4MB each

I'm using actors in Tokio to handle the connections with the grpc servers and a mpsc Chanel for communication

my question is whether this approach may lead to buttlenecks in the channel and if this may increase the memory utilization if for example I'm reading and writing 1GBps or what are some considerations I may need to make